# Initialising mock in new objects

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

My class cannot autowired UserService - it throws NullPointerException. I would like to find a way to test UserValidator class. I don't know how to inject mocks in ExistingValidationRule class.

```
public class ExistingValidationRule implements RegistrationRule<User> {
@Autowired
private UserService service;

@Override
public void validate(User user, Errors errors) {

    service.find(user, errors);
}
}


@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;
        rules.add(new ExistingValidationRule());

        for(RegistrationRule<User> rule : rules){
            rule.validate(user, errors);
        }
    }
}

public class UserValidatorTest {
@InjectMocks
private UserValidator userValidator;

@InjectMocks
private ExistingValidationRule existingValidationRule;

@Mock
private UserService service;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
    public void testValidUser() throws Exception{

        userValidator.validate(createdUser,errors);
}
```

Comment: If you use `new` to create Spring bean instances, they're not Spring bean instances anymore, and can thus not be autowired by Spring, which has no way to know that this instance even exists. Autowire the ExistingValidationRule instance into UserValidator.

Comment: When most of your questions get voted down, you're doing something to annoy a lot of people. Perhaps lack of homework is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserValidator  
// if all roles that you need are spring beans- then do autowired then by super type
@Autowired 
privete Collection<RegistrationRule> roles ;

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    User user = (User) o;

    // all spring-bean configured validators were autowired 
    for(RegistrationRule<User> rule : rules){ 
        rule.validate(user, errors);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {
    //if rules was created before
    @Autowired
    public void setExistingValidationRule(ExistingValidationRule existingValidationRule){
        rules.add(existingValidationRule);
    }

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    User user = (User) o;

    for(RegistrationRule<User> rule : rules){
        rule.validate(user, errors);
    }
}
```

and try to avoid adding new responsibility in method validate() - like add new validator. method validate  should do only validation , nothing more

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` is a Spring annotation and unless you run your unit test with a Spring test runner, this will just not do anything.

However, `@InjectMocks` of Mockito will just fill your fields with Mocks, as long as you provide a constructor to reach those fields. Try the following:

```
public class ExistingValidationRule implements RegistrationRule<User> {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    public ExistingValidationRule(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public ExistingValidationRule() {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(User user, Errors errors) {

        service.find(user, errors);
    }
}
```

I added a second empty constructor for making Spring happy. The first one should do the trick for your unit test.

Happy testing!